# What is this Murkrift on the world map for?

Tags: world-of-final-fantasy

This evening I noticed for the first time that there was a Murkrift displayed on the World Map.

[image: World map murkrift]

The Murkrift is visible just to the right hand side of the chain above the Bihydra.

Does this mean that Dragon Scars has an uncleared Murkrift? I am on Chapter 19 at the moment, in case game progression has any relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those Murkrifts are accessible directly on the 'world map' by using the Airship (which is automatically obtained through progression of the main story), once you fly into them you will have the same option to view the battle level and enter the Murkrift.

There are multiple Murkrifts accessible from the world map using the Airship.

They are not an indicator of any uncleared Murkrifts within a level.